# Mongoose how to find by array of ids and pull its specific sub document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following documents:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb81"),
   likedBy: [
     {
        "userId" : ObjectId("59edd922df2339579fc2a528"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c199f93b7ab1004c4318")
     },
     {
        "userId" : ObjectId("59edd922df2339579fc2a448"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c199f93b7ab1004c4412")
     }
   ]
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb83"),
   likedBy: [
     {
        "userId" : ObjectId("59edd922df2339579fc2a528"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c199f93b7ab1004c4323")
     },
     {
        "userId" : ObjectId("59edd922df2339579fc2a448"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a13c199f93b7ab1004c6423")
     }
   ]
}
```

What i want to do is find all documents that their id is in `["59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb81", "59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb83"]`, and remove subdocument that its `userId` is `59edd922df2339579fc2a528`. i want to remove all likes of specific user from specific documents (array of documents) in one query.
with looping through id array i can do, but i want to pass ids and pull.
My current query working with one id:

```
post
  .findByIdAndUpdate(postId, {$pull: {likedBy: {userId: userId}}}, {new: true}, function (err, post) {
    if (err) {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
    } else {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 204, post);
    }
  });
```

What i want to is to pass an array of post id and pull likes of specific user among all matched documents.

Comment: Your model is seriously flawed. The number ofblikes will be limited. Please see https://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb.html as a primer. Disclosure as per site requirements: I am the author.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I can change `likedBy` sub document structure like `follows: [
    ObjectId("5637c7140a55d1434116a2fa"),
    ObjectId("5637c7350a55d1434116a2fb"),
    ObjectId("5637c7350a55d1434116a2fc"),
    ObjectId("5637c7350a55d1434116a2fd")
  ]`, in your blog, but my main problem is with find by array of ids.

Comment: The problem is that a) subdocuments are just a notion without any technical meaning, b) a lot of likes will eventually hit the 16MB size limit and c) embedded documents are the #1 performance crusher, as basically you do a "find, modify & save" cycle for each like instead of a simple insert with a dedicated `likes` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
post.update(
    {
        _id: {
            $in: [
                ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb83"),
                ObjectId("59e4540bf14f1607b90ffb81")
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            likedBy: {
                $or: [
                    { userId: ObjectId("59edd922df2339579fc2a448") },
                    { userId: ObjectId("59edd922df2339579fc2a528") }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        multi: true
    },
    function(err, rawResponse) {
        /*...*/
    }
);
```